Things gets ended before with apacite and url bib
I hope someone can help me to spot and solve the errors in this code:
%DISEÑO Y FORMATO DE DOCUMENTO
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
%CARGA DE PAQUETES
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [a4paper, left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%CARGA DE PAQUETES

%COMANDOS DE FORMATO
\makeatletter
\renewcommand {\baselinestretch}{2}
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}{}{0pt}{}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}{}{0pt}{}
%COMANDOS DE FORMATO

\begin{document}
\cite{cancino2022}

%aquí empieza el código para las referencias.
\pagebreak
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{liblib.bib}

\end{document}

this is the specific reference I wanted to use:
@online{cancino2022,
    author = {Cancino, F. C.},
    title = {El Caballo de Troya: edición crítica de los Treinta cantos araucanos de Carlos Isamitt Alarcón},
    date = {Date},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.4067/S0716-2790202200020000%0D%0A},
    year = {2022},
}

for some reason, I get four errors in the log.

Paragraph ended before \url was complete.
\begin{APACrefURL} on input line 48 ended by \end{thebibliograph
\begin{thebibliography} on input line 1 ended by \end{document}.
Underfull \hbox (badness 3557) in paragraph at lines 14--26 (this one disappears if I delete and force to make a .bbl again on this simplified code)

Thanks for reading beforehand!

Off-topic: left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm may be expressed more succinctly as margin-1in.

@Mico I think margin=1in would work better and margin=2.54cm would have the advantage of being intelligible. ;)

welcome! you are missing a closing curly bracket for the .bib entry.

also \bibliography{liblib} without the extension

Load \usepackage{apacite} after \usepackage{hyperref}. Better move these two \usepackage lines to the end of the preamble, since hyperref is best loaded as one of the last packages (or at least that used to be the case). If you don't like the links, use \usepackage{url} instead of \usepackage{hyperref}.

crf, oops I forgot to copy that curly bracket in the post. also I tried ur suggestions but I still have the problem

moewe, post ur comment as a answer so I can mark u as a solution! I just loaded the url package and all problems got solved! thank u very much.

On its own apacite has only rudimentary support for URLs and DOIs and the like. In particular not all special characters (like %) will work properly.
The solution is to load either \usepackage{hyperref} or \usepackage{url} before \usepackage{apacite} so that apacite can make use of their facilities.
The following document compiles without error and generates a clickable URL
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [a4paper, left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{cancino2022,
  author = {Cancino, F. C.},
  title  = {El Caballo de Troya: edición crítica de los Treinta cantos araucanos de Carlos Isamitt Alarcón},
  url    = {https://doi.org/10.4067/S0716-2790202200020000%0D%0A},
  year   = {2022},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\cite{cancino2022}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}

Note, however, that 10.4067/S0716-2790202200020000%0D%0A is not a valid DOI. Do you maybe want 10.4067/S0716-27902022000200009?

hmmm yeah, that doi doesn't work, idk why I have that corrupted link. Thanks a lot!
